# Laravel - Regular Expression to validate credit card expiry

Tags: php, regex, validation

I am working with the validator of laravel. I want to validate a credit card expiry date.

The input has a input mask `99/99` - `MM/YY`. 
I want to validate also the year of the expression. So if **YY** < 15 = validation fails.

If **YY** > 25 = validation fails.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `\/(?:1[6-9]|2[0-4])` try this with regex if it is only for year.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library that checks all data of a credit card

you install it through composer

```
"require": {
    "inacho/php-credit-card-validator": "1.*"
},
```

then you can validate dates like this;

```
$validDate = CreditCard::validDate('2013', '07'); // past date
var_dump($validDate);
```

or if you don't want to do that you can send year and month in separate fields (actually you should) and then at the validator check for a minimum and a maximum `number min:1|max:12` 
for month and

```
min:2015|max:2025 for year
```

In more detail:

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
                        array(
                            'month'  =>'required|max:12|min:1'                            
                            )
                        );     

            if($validator->fails())
               {
              Session::flash('flash_message', 'Check the date you entered');
              return Redirect::to('checkcreditcard')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);                 
               }            
           else
            {
```

UPDATE:

This will give you the current year in 2 digits format, (so it will give, 15)

```
$this_year = date("y");
```

then in the validator you can do:

```
min:$this_year|max:$this_year+10
```

slaba rossii!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expression to do this. Just look at the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-digits-between).
(I refer to version 5.1, but it's mostly the same in the previous versions).

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'year' => 'required|digits_between:15,25',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I have improven the answer (hopefully) and included the code to determine the current year and the year 10 years after, so it is dynamic.